# Estimation of fractional expression

Tags: fractions, maxima-minima, monotone-functions

We define

> $$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^{2y}-\frac{1}{4^y}}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2y}-\frac{1}{4^y}} \text{ for } (x,y) \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right) \times \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$$.

A study with Maple suggests that

> $$f(x,y) \geq f(0,1)=-\frac{8}{3} \text{ for } (x,y) \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right) \times \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$$

Is someone able to prove this analytically? The derivatives, unfortunately, don't look very nice.

I'm glad about every idea!

Comment: Are you searching for a minimum of $$f(x,y)$$?

Comment: Exactly, i'm looking for the minimum of $f(x,y)$ in $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\times\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $x$, the derivative of $f(x,y)$ is given by $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-\frac{4^y(\ln4+4^y(1-x)^{2y}\ln(1-x)^2}{(4^y(1-x)^{2y}-1)^2} - \frac{4^y(\ln4+4^y (x^{2y}\ln x^2)}{(4^y x^{2y}-1)^2}<0$$ Hence $f$ is decreasing with increasing $y$, and so takes its minimum value for $y=1$.

$$f(x,1)=\frac{1}{x^2-4^{-1}}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2-4^{-1}}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,1)=32\times\frac{1-2x}{(3+4x-4x^2)^2}$$ It is easy to check that this fraction is positive in the given range, so the minimum is achieved at the smallest allowed value of $x$, namely $0$.

Edit: To prove the first inequality, first simplify it via $a:=e^y$, $t:=-\log_4(4x^2)$, $s=-\log_44(1-x)^2$, $$-\frac{1}{4^y\ln4}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{1-a^s(1-s)}{(a^s-1)^2}+\frac{1-a^t(1-t)}{(a^t-1)^2}$$ This can be shown by splitting the ranges of $s$ and $t$.

Comment: How do you proof that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}<0$? I think this is the crucial part.

Comment: Nice simplification, but I think you mean $a:=4^y, t:=\log_4(4x^2), s:=\log_4 4(1-x)^2$. The problem now is that one has to take notice of the constraint $2^s+2^t=2$. How would you split the ranges of $s$ and $t$?

Comment: If you plot their graphs, you'll notice that over some range, both are positive. When one is negative, you can subdivide the range so that the minimum of the positive one is larger than the maximum of the negative one, etc. I did not notice $2^s+2^t=2$ in the rush; if that's the case, I would probably use $S=s-1$ and $T=t-1$ as my main variables so that $2^S+2^T=1$ and try to think of the problem as a convex combination. Sorry but I don't have time to revisit the problem.

Comment: The problem seems to be hard. Does anyone else have an idea how to proceed?